# Highcharts renderer.rect on xAxis label not responsive

Tags: highcharts

I have set my xAxis label background color in my column type chart using chart.renderer.rect() method but it's not responsive to screen resizing. My goal is to extend the plotband to extend to the xAxis label on one column by drawing rectangle around xAxis. Notices that the highlight extends to March instead of staying on January. How to make it responsive.
[FiddleLink](http://jsfiddle.net/n607a68n/1/)

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
          events: {
                    // Highlights the specialty labels at the bottom of the chart. Also see plotBands settings below
                    load: function() {
                        let chart = this;
                        let xAxis = chart.xAxis[0];
                        let yAxis = chart.yAxis[0];
                        let top = chart.plotTop + yAxis.height;
                        let height = 60; // Stretches the highlight to the bottom
                        let options = {
                                fill: 'rgb(235, 236, 238, 0.5)'
                            };
                        // colorize from -1 to .5
                        let start_1 = xAxis.toPixels(-0.5);
                        let end_5 = xAxis.toPixels(.5);

                        let rect1 = chart.renderer.rect(
                            start_1,
                            top,
                            end_5 - start_1,
                            height
                        ).attr(options).add();
                    }
                },
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Threshold is set to 100'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Mar']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            threshold: 2
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [10, -5],
        zones: [{
                    value: 0,
                    color: '#233b66'
                }]
    }]
});
```

```css
#container {
 max-width: 800px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the rect dimensions on chart resize/redraw event.

```
function rectDimensions(chart) {
  const xAxis = chart.xAxis[0]
  const yAxis = chart.yAxis[0]

  const top = yAxis.top + yAxis.height
  const height = 60

  const x1 = xAxis.toPixels(-0.5)
  const x2 = xAxis.toPixels(0.5)

  return {
    x: x1,
    y: top,
    width: x2 - x1,
    height
  }
}


Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    events: {
      // Highlights the specialty labels at the bottom of the chart. Also see plotBands settings below
      load: function() {
        const chart = this
        const dimensions = rectDimensions(chart)

        let options = {
          fill: 'rgb(235, 236, 238, 0.5)'
        };

        this.rect1 = chart.renderer
          .rect()
          .attr(Object.assign(dimensions, options))
          .add();

      },

      redraw() {
        this.rect1.attr(rectDimensions(this))
      }
    }
  },
```

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/3xg17bby/

Comment: You're awesome! I appreciate it.